Vs code auto pause running when calling any API
Every time any Flutter app is running in the Android Emulator (it doesn't happen in a real device) and it's calling any API of any type (get, post, put, etc), even when it has to load an Image.network widget, vs code automatically pause the app running. So, every single time the app calls any API i have to tap the "play" button again. For example, if i have a view with 15 different Image.network widgets, i have to tap 15 times the "play" button.
It also occurs every time there is an Exception; i have to tap the play button in several points of the stack trace of the exception.
I am not forgetting break points. That happens in every Flutter application in the emulator, every time there is an API calling, an information download from any url, or an exception.

What can i do to solve this? Please!!

The reason for this issue is that you are mistakenly using debug points, which are meant for debugging purposes. I believe you added debug points to each image, which activates them for every image.
Solution: To run your code without debugging, simply remove all debug points.

No, i checked that long time ago. This is not a thing of one app and/or one Flutter view. As i said earlier, every time any app call an API the app pauses automatically.

@Jhonatan, Make sure you are using "await" when calling the async functions

Yes, i am using await. I forgot to mention that it also happens with exceptions.
